# How to darken the Darcula UI theme in JetBRAINS IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

I have been somewhat disappointed in the readability of the "dark" theme called Darcula in IDEA environments.  I was certainly hoping for some darker elements and higher contrast in some spots (particularly with UI text color choices).

Is there any way to modify the Darcula UI theme (not the Editor color theme) or to find a darker theme that is a bit more refined in terms of contrast?

Answer (score 4):

IDE themes, like Darcula, are java Look&Feels. There is no way to edit a theme - it's hardcoded. It's technically possible to install any third-party L&F into JVM and use it in IDEA ( see https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kirillcool/archive/2005/08/intellij_idea_5.html for instructions), but it will most likely look ugly and break the UI in many places.